# This is John Doe vs I am John Doe. (In an e-mail)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Which is a better or common way to introduce myself in an e-mail to a person who I never met before?

1. This is John Doe, a university student at Clearwater College.
2. I am John Doe, a university student at Clearwater College.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't typically identify yourself by name in the first line of an email, as you would in the first few words of a phone call you had made to someone who doesn't know you.  Instead, you'd use the first-person pronoun "I" and give your name on the signature line at the bottom.

> I'm a student at _________ University and am hoping to get your advice
>   on an upcoming project, since you're an alum and a recognized expert
>   in the field.
>
> etc etc
>
> Regards
>
> John Doe

Of course, you'd change the words to suit the circumstances :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my native culture, we MUST mention our name first in an business e-mail especially to someone we have never met. Without this, all the e-mails would be considered as a spam without exception. Signature in the bottom is just a supplemental, and will NOT be considered enough. Do you feel this feeling to some degree or not at all?

Comment: Those are concerns unrelated to English language per se. But most native speakers of AmE would regard as suspicious any email in which the sender introduces themselves in the first line. The email I receive where that is the practice is usually from a prince who needs my help in transferring a billion dollars into a US account, for which he is willing to pay me a few million dollars.

Comment: Wow! I see. I have never thought adding the name in the beginning makes others feel more suspicious. Thank you so much! This means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer given by Tᴚoɯɐuo –  most of the time, there's really no need to put your name at the start of an email.

That said, if you really felt the need to identify yourself atop an email, I wouldn't use "This is" or "I am". Instead, I'd say "My name is":

> My name is John Doe, a university student at Clearwater College.

"This is John" works fine over the phone, but it may sound a bit out-of-place in email traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "My name is xxx." feels more fit to me. When you are sending the second or third e-mail to the same person, do you mention your name in the beginning?
The reason is the person might not register my name on his or her e-mail registry, and might not be able to recognize me. If the person do not recognize, there is higher chance to have no reply. How would you avoid this type of situations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChristmasBoy, no, after you've been introduced, there's no need to write your name into the message text. The other person has probably looked at the "From:" field in their message list before even deciding to open the email and read the body. Of course this means you might rather use an email handle like "JohnSmith@server.com" instead of "partyguy@server.com" if you're going to use that email for work or school.

Comment: Doesn't sound idiomatic to me to say "My name is X, a student...."  The apposition only works with "I am X, a student..."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - I guess it depends on what the rest of the email says. I feel like the _My name is X_ intro could work as an introduction to a long missive.